# sort array if element contains value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to sort array correctly so that all elements containing "●" are moved to the end of the array?

```
const data = ["ac", "ba●●●", "cd●", "df●●", "ea", "fc●", "ga"];
```

Comment: What will be your expected output?

Comment: Should elements on the end be sorted too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need any specific sorting, this would do the job:

```
const sortedData = []
    .concat(
        data.map(e => !e.includes('●') && e),
        data.map(e => e.includes('●') && e)
    )
    .filter(e => e)
```

What it does:

- `data.map(e => !e.includes('●') && e)` creates a new array from data with all elements without '●'
- the next line does the same with all elements containing '●'
- concat combines the two array to a new array
- then the filter takes out all falsy elements

If you'd like the data sorted by how many occurrences of '●' there are in the elements, this solution would work:

```
const countOccurrences = x => (x.match(/●/g) || []).length
const compareFunc = (a, b) => countOccurrences(a) - countOccurrences(b)
const sortedData = data.sort(compareFunc)
```

- first we need a function to count occurrences of '●' (using regex)
- then we need a comparison function that determines what order we sort (ascending, descending, ...)
- then we need to sort the initial array using the two first functions

Comment: It would be great if we also sorted by the number of '●'. But this solution is already working! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why call `.map()` twice then `.filter()` instead of just calling `.filter()` twice?

Comment: @VladimirMelnikov I added a solution that sorts by the number of '●'.

Comment: @VLAZ interesting question - what do you suggest? Would be nice to see your solution.

Comment: `[].concat(data.filter(e => !e.includes('●')), data.filter(e => e.includes('●')))`

Comment: Very nice @VLAZ I like that solution better than the first one I posted. It's more readable and even has slightly better performance. If you spot optimization potential in my 2nd solution as well, I would be interested in that feedback.

Comment: The second solution is also fine by number of `●`. OP hasn't specified if that should happen or how, so I can't say it's wrong. However, I'd personally have a second sorting criteria, to make sure the result is consistent, otherwise two words with the same number of `●` might appear in different position in relation to each other.  `(a, b) => (countOccurrences(a) - countOccurrences(b)) || a.localeCompare(b)`. However, that's not stated as a requirement, just my personal approach here.

Comment: Good idea. I hope OP keeps reading until here. (he did mention in his first comment to my solution that sorting would be nice)

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. I'll try all the options! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As you mention google-sheets as a tag, I propose how to do it using google sheets formula:

[image]

First you filter your range for elements NOT containing black dot,
then you filter your range for elements that contain black dot.
You sort both ranges and stack one over another.

```
={sort(filter(I4:I10,regexmatch(I4:I10,"●")=false));
sort(filter(I4:I10,regexmatch(I4:I10,"●")))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the object reference, you could sort the array by taking the delta of the boolean values of checking the string for the unwanted string.

```js
const data = ["ac", "ba●●●", "cd●", "df●●", "ea", "fc●", "ga"];

data.sort((a, b) => a.includes('●') - b.includes('●'));

console.log(data);
```